How to access camera "hidden by the manufacturer"?
My phone has three cameras, two rear and one front, but when I call either of the Camera APIs it only reports 2 cameras (one of the rear and the front) and the 2nd rear camera appears to be missing?

int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
Log.d("tag","numCameras camera1:" + numCameras);
CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String[] cameraIds = camManager.getCameraIdList();
Log.d("tag","numCameras camera2:" + cameraIds.length);

Each API call returns only two cameras:
numCameras camera1:2
numCameras camera2:2
However the 2nd rear camera shows up in some 3rd party camera apps but is apparently "hidden" by the manufacturer. How do I go about accessing this camera?

Very likely, the camera is simply not listed in the set of camera IDs returned by getCameraIdList, but methods like getCameraCharacteristics or openCamera work with the hidden ID.  So these apps probably just try small integer IDs with getCameraCharacteristics and see if they get back info instead of an invalid ID exception.
But since they are unlisted, they are not tested for Android compliance, and they may not follow the API's specifications.  And each unlisted camera may have its own different set of quirks and limitations; there is a reason they're not being listed after all.  To use them reliably would require testing each unlisted device and possibly retesting after every major OS update - there are no guarantees at all about them.
